# Dynamic wagtail page

Tags: javascript, django, wagtail

Can anyone tell me about dynamic pages in wagtail?

My use case is as following:

1. I have a number of objects (images) on the main page
2. When I click on image I'd like to be redirected to a page about this object (I can get detailed info about object via ajax)
3. But I don't want to create pages for each object. I would rather make smth like this: mysite.com/images?image_id=254 (with a model and template for such page)

Can it be done? If so please tell me where to look in documentation xx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds like an ideal use for [RoutablePageMixin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html), which allows you to define multiple views for one page, using Django-like URL patterns. In this case, you could define two views, one for the main page (at the URL `/images/`) and one for a specific object (at the URL `/images/123/`):

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from wagtail.contrib.routable_page.models import RoutablePageMixin, route

class ProductListingPage(RoutablePageMixin, Page):

    @route(r'^$')
    def index_view(self, request):
        # render the index view
        return render(request, 'products/index.html', {
            'page': self,
        })

    @route(r'^(\d+)/$')
    def product_view(self, request, product_id):
        # render the view for a single item
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        return render(request, 'products/product.html', {
            'product': product,
            'page': self,
        })
```

If you want to go lower-level, you can try [overriding the page's `serve` method](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3.1/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#overriding-the-serve-method) - this is how `RoutablePageMixin` works internally. Overriding `serve` is sufficient to support URLs like mysite.com/images?image_id=254 :

```
class ProductListingPage(Page):
    def serve(self, request):
        product_id = request.GET.get('image_id', None)
        if product_id is None:
            return render(request, 'products/index.html', {
                'page': self,
            })
        else:
            product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
            return render(request, 'products/product.html', {
                'product': product,
                'page': self,
            })
```

To get nicer URLs of the form mysite.com/images/123/, you could [override the `route` method](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.3.1/reference/pages/model_recipes.html#adding-endpoints-with-custom-route-methods) as well.

Comment: Note to future visitors: as of at least Wagtail 1.10, don't put `.` in your `@route`s! Wagtail's page serving mechanism doesn't consider `.` to be a valid character for Page URLs. So, e.g. `news/feed.rss` will not even engage the Page router, and will always trigger a 404.